# Cannot run ios simulator using titanium studio 3.1.0 in MAC OS 10.6.8

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Good day all,

Im using titanium studio 3.1.0 with xcode 3.2.6 in MAC OS 10.6.8.
When i create new ios application and run simulator this error come out:

Accepted values: 
[ERROR] Invalid --ios-version value '4.3'

But if i create new application through xcode it will run simulator like normal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you need to follow the version match between titanium sdk, ios dk and mac os version.

You can refer link i provide below.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-TitaniumStudio